# Eclipse C project not recognized as root

Tags: c, eclipse, root, sudo, eclipse-cdt

I have imported an Existing Code as Makefile (C) Project in Eclipse which I setup for debugging. Unfortunately I need to run the executable as root with sudo. When I start sudo eclipse the project seems to be a normal Java project or anything, but not as the c project that I setup as user. CDT seems to be there.

What could be the problem?

Comment: It's not a good idea to run development code as root. Why do you feel the need to do this?

Comment: because a non persistent tap interface is created which needs root rights. but I have just seen that CDT is not recognized when eclipse is started as root.

Comment: installing CDT again helped